# Saving .htacess passwords on iPad

Tags: ipad, password

I know it is possible to save form username/passwords on the iPad's Safari browser. The thing I can't do is to save .htaccess username and passwords. In case you don't know what those are, it's when a webpage is protected and you can't even see the page without authenticating. It usually displays a popup window so you can authenticate.

Is it possible to save this type of credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more secure solution, I'd suggest [1Password for iPad](http://agilebits.com/onepassword/ipad). It has many useful features, not the least of which are auto-generation of strong passwords (so you can use a different password on each site) and strong encryption of your passwords. You can use 1Password with HTTP Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is HTTP Authentication and the iPad cannot "remember" the credentials of these sorts of logins.  It has no problems with a normal web form however.

If you are happy to have your username and password stored in plain text on a bookmark in Safari however, there is a way to allow you to login without filling out those details again.

Just visit the site with the following formatted url :

```
http://username:password@domain.com/
```

Rememer to change the 3 obvious variables (username, password and domain).  This should log you straight in.  You can save this as a book mark and then use that going forward.

The username and password must be URL encoded if they contain any special characters.

Just remember that anyone who picks up your iPad could view the bookmarks and see the clear text username and password, so I wouldn't use this on your banks website :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you bank uses basic/digest authentication, stop using it... Chiefly because you don't know if they're using basic or digest authentication.

Comment: Also note that using this method would mean you are sending your username and password in plaintext so anyone on your network could potentially see this. If you're not connected to your home wifi, then this is not a good idea.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I can't imagine for the life of me why that matters. Most banks use "forms" authentication and that certainly isn't any more inherently secure than http basic authentication, presuming the connection is made over HTTPS. On the other hand, there seem to be people who think a site is secure if it's using digest authentication but not using HTTPS, which is a fallacy.  Apple preventing the iOS Safari browser from saving basic passwords is irritating.

Comment: I think I agree with you, I argue that HTTP authentication is terrible for UX (though browser's have gotten smart about toning how modal the prompts are), but security-wise you're right. HTTPS > Basic or Digest by far.

Comment: Also, that 5 year bump, though...